# How can I prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{\lambda}}$ converges for $\lambda \in (0,2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> How can I prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{\lambda}}$
>   converges for $\lambda \in (0,2)$?

I tried substituting $\sin(x)$ trough its series represantation in order to get rid of the $x^{\lambda}$ in the denominator when I realised that there the series represantation encompasses $(-1)^k$ and $!$.

How can I go about solving this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x^p}\, dx$ converges for $0<p<2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064025/prove-that-int-0-infty-frac-sin-xxp-dx-converges-for-0p2)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2665616, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/390809.